# Test - DeploymentItem - outputDirectory will be ignored

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I use

```
<Deployment>
   <DeploymentItem filename="TestProject1\Config\" outputDirectory="TestConfig" /><br>
</Deployment>
```

in the Local.testsettings to copy all files under TestProject1\Config\ to 'TestRoot'\TestConfig\, but it copies the files direct in the Test 'TestRoot' folder.

Answer (score 6):

I found out that it work after restarting Visual Studio. A rebuild of the solution or clicking the Refresh button in the TestListEditor will not include a change/setting of the outputDirectory attribute in of DeploymentItem....

Comment: I couldn't make it work for copying the folder, works only if you specify the files one by one.