# MsTest DeploymentItem OutputDirectory in testsettings

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

How can I specify output directory when I create DeploymentItem in testsettings? It is easy when you apply DeploymentItem attribute to method or class (there is a special constructor parameter) but I don't see a way to apply it in testsettings (and even UI doesn't contain anything like this).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try editing the *testrunconfig* file either from VS or using an XML editor - right-click and choose *open with* and add a line like this one:

```
<Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="rootdir\SomeDir\" outputDirectory="SomeDir" />
```

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. Files are copied to the root of build folder

Comment: Use the OutputDirectory to set where the files are copied to

Comment: This should work. The key is the trailing \  -- and -- VS only reads these settings when the solution is loaded, so make the change and then close VS down and then back up again.

Comment: @bryanbcook, thank you for the hint: I really had to restart Visual Studio

Comment: Looks like you might also need to restart VS for these settings to take into effect as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791161/test-deploymentitem-outputdirectory-will-be-ignored

Comment: I couldn't make it work for copying the folder, works only if you specify the files one by one.

Answer (score 2):

**In visual studio 2010:**

1. Go to Test
2. Edit Test Settings
3. .testsettings
4. Go to Deployment
5. Add your file 'myfile.txt' via Add File...

Close Visual Studio 2010

Go to your project root directory in windows explorer
Open the .testsettings file
Locate this line:

```
<DeploymentItem filename="<somedir>\<otherdir>\myfile.txt" />
```

change it to the output directory that you want:

```
<DeploymentItem filename="<somedir>\<otherdir>\myfile.txt" outputDirectory="<otherdir>" />
```

Start Visual Studio 2010 again :-)

**For Visual Studio 2012:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx

> Unit tests run more slowly if you use a test settings file. We recommend that you do not use a test settings file with unit tests.
>   You can configure unit tests by using the .runsettings file instead.
>   To deploy additional files, use DeploymentItemAttribute.
>
> But web performance and load tests always use a test settings file.

Upgrading from 2010 to 2012:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh507838.aspx