# How to get build directory of a test project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a test project in which I needs to load an XLSX file. For that, I added a file with copy-always so that it ends up in the build directory, but all of the following return a wrong path:

1. `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(testclass)).Location;`
2. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
3. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

They all give me:

`"C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\visual-studio-projecten\\projectname\\TestResults\\username_ICT003 2012-06-20 12_07_06\\Out"`

and I need

`"C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\visual-studio-projecten\\projectname\\TestProject\\bin\\Debug\\SupportFiles\\"`

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) attribute. To quote MSDN:

This attribute identifies files and directories that contain files that are used by the deployed test to run. The test engine makes a copy of the deployment items and places them in test deployment directory based upon the OutputDirectory specified or the default directory.

For example:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("myfile.txt")]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {          
        string file = "myfile.txt";           
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(file), "deployment failed: " + file +
            " did not get deployed");
    }
}
```

Of course assuming you are using MSTest as your testing framework.

Comment: It works, but I have to do really funky things to get files in subdirs to be deployed. Specifying the file like `SupportFiles\dir\bla.xls` doesn't work, but if I say `SupportFiles\dir` is a deployment item, the xls file in that dir gets deployed in the root dir of the output. And I have to set `copy always` on it.

Comment: [DeploymentItem] takes an optional second arg to specify the destination path

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
string dir = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    "SupportFiles");
```

Don't use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` because current directory could not be your exe dir and may change during program execution.

Comment: +1 for `Don't use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() because current directory could not be your exe dir and may change during program execution.`

Comment: Didn't help, still the testresults dir. I had actually already tried that one, but forgot. I tried it again to be sure.

Comment: @Halfgaar: which is the build directory? I'm pretty sure it should work, I always use it!!!

Comment: It's the needed path I mentioned. The XLS file is also in that location, as well as the libs and executables.

Comment: @Halfgaar: if you run your main exe from the dir you need and show a messagebox with my `dir` value, what do you get?

Comment: This will still return the location of the executable in most cases, as dependent assemblies are copied to the "main" bin directory, and executed from there.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone like me comes along, if you're using a **.testsettings file** and the **DeploymentItem attribute** on the class **doesn't work** even though you've set your files as Content and to Always Copy, it's because either you already have a Deployment section in your .testsettings file or you need to use DeploymentItem in the .testsettings file.  Here's how ours looks now:

```
<Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="Tests\Unit Tests\ConnectionStrings.config" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="Tests\Unit Tests\<project dir>\bin\Debug\TestFiles\" outputDirectory="TestFiles" />
</Deployment>
```

One does a file, the other does 13 files in a directory.  Note the trailing slash for the directory's "filename"!

Solution and more info was found at:

[MsTest DeploymentItem OutputDirectory in testsettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289503/mstest-deploymentitem-outputdirectory-in-testsettings)

Answer (score 1):

Switch to **xUnit** or **NUnit**.

Then both option 2., 3. and `Environment.CurrentDirectory` works as needed, returning the build-output-diretory. Remove "bin\Debug" or "bin\Release" and files can be left at 'Do not copy'.

Also see the [GetFileFromMethod](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/BaseJsonTests.cs#L122-L131)-method and [usage](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/tree/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/AnalyzerField) in ElasticSearch for a nice way to have one file per test.