# MSTest processes in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

When running multiple MSTest.exe processes without any configuration (testsettings and DeploymentItem attributes configured) in parallel there is a problem, the MSTest runtime creates a folder for each process named **user_machine_data time_configuration**, as i run multiple processes very fast (less than a second of difference) two instances of MSTest.exe may use the same folder for testing giving me conflicts on the tests.

Does anyone knows a way to configure the name of the folder the MSTest creates for the TestDeploymentDir?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MsTest DeploymentItem OutputDirectory in testsettings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289503/mstest-deploymentitem-outputdirectory-in-testsettings)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue by passing the MSTest.exe command line the parameter **/resultsfilesroot:"{DifferentFolderName}"** and removing the **/resultsfile:"customName.trx"** because it will give an error if the two are used at the same time. 
I passed a different name for each process, creating a unique environment(folder) for each MSTest.exe allowing me to run multiple that are not safe thread but are in different assemblies.

Note: the folder that is passed to the resultfileroot must exist before calling the MSTest.exe process.